# Redirecionar sem ser detectado

Tags: php, html

Eu gostaria de meu usuário fosse redirecionado sem que ele fosse detectado a origem.

Exemplo:`<a href="ola.php">oi</a>`
O ola.php pega a origem, com o atributo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

Gostaria que meu usuário fosse redirecionado sem ser detectado pelo http_referer, é possível?

Comment: Utilize `<a href="ola.php" rel="noreferrer">oi</a>`

Comment: Obrigado amigo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei um meio:

```
<a href="http://example.com" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">ReferrerPolicy Attribute</a>
```

Ou modificar o head do seu html adicionando a meta:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

mas ai seria para todos os links.

Encontrei em:
http://geekthis.net/post/hide-http-referer-headers/

Saudações,

Comment: Obrigado rodrigo! :D